# how can I overlay multiple canvas

Tags: canvas, easeljs

I'm trying to make two functions add seed and remove seed... all they do is place a little start on a canvas at a mouse point and then remove it at a mouse point, the trouble is If  i use removeChildAt It deletes other overlays I don't want to remove.. I was thinking I could put all the "seeds" or points on a seperate canvas and overlay that canvas on top of the other..

button1 overlays an image I don't want deleted, button 2 add's a point and button 3 removes the last point...

here's my code

```
            stage = new createjs.Stage("demoCanvas");
            seedstage = new createjs.Stage("demoCanvas2");
            stage.onload = setBG();
```

.... I was thinking I could make two stages, a seedstage that kept track of the seeds so i could add remove them... is that possible?

```
    items:[{ 
       itemId: 'button1',
       xtype: 'button',
       text: 'click the button',
       visible: true,
       enableToggle: true,

       toggleHandler:
       function(button, pressed){
           if(button.pressed==true){
               overImage = new Image();
               overImage.src = "stuff.jpg";
               overlay = new createjs.Bitmap(overImage);
               overImage.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
                                       // stage.enableMouseOver(30);
                                        overlay.alpha=0.5;
                                        }); 

               stage.addChild(overlay);

               stage.update();
               }
            else
             {stage.removeChild(overlay);
             stage.update();
             }

        }// end func




        },{
        itemId: 'button2',
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'addSeed',
        enableToggle: true,
        handler: function(button, pressed)
          {
           if(button.pressed==true)
                {
                bgrd.addEventListener('click', onClick )   

                } 
           else {
                bgrd.removeEventListener('click',onClick)

                } //end addeventlistener
           }
         },{
         itemID: 'button3',
         xtype:'button',
         text:'remove seed',

         handler: function(){

            stage.removeChildAt(stage.getNumChildren()-1);
            stage.update();
         }
        }]
```

Comment: Don't you maybe have a reference to that 'seed'? Then you could use `mySeed.parent.removeChild(mySeed);` instead of `removeChildAt` - (As a sidenote, NOT related to your question: I started out just like you by just fiddeling around and writing horrible code ;) - however I noticed most your questions are usually covered by basic tutorials, so my advice would be that you should really conside doing some basic tutorials instead of a new question on SO for every little step of your project, trust me, you'll profit more from that even if the tutorials are not directly related to your project ;) )

Comment: well there's multiple seeds being placed, cos there points, and yeah but I'm kind of trying to do something specific for a video game website im trying to make on my own... I find that if I have an actual goal I am more interested in working on it. If i'm just randomly doing things unrelated to each other I get bored

Comment: what I ended up doing is rendering all my overlayed images prior to adding seeds then just used .alpha to toggle visibility and then an if statemen (if getNumChildren > myChildrenCounter) remove seed